# Как добавить изображение над кнопкой через скрипт?

Tags: c#, android, unity3d

У меня есть календарь. Нажимая на дату, перехожу на сцену со стикерами, выбираю стикер, он появляется над датой.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Просто к слову, зачем делать чистое UI приложение на Unity? Ведь уже есть куча всего готового для разработки, например под Xamarin.Forms, и ресурсов жрать меньше будет. Unity вроде для игр же.

Comment: Посоветовали. Надо было сделать быстро.

Comment: Это выглядит как, чтобы добраться из пукта А в пункт Б, вы выбрали пассажирский самолет и едете на нем по шоссе. Горючки жрет много, огромный, а где-то вообще не проехать, и прочие недостатки. На самолетах летать надо, передайте привет своим советчикам. Здесь вам вряд-ли помогут, потому что задача совсем нетипичная для Unity. Если хочется простой и гибкий UI - Xamarin.Forms ваш выбор.

Comment: @aepot А почему она не типичная для Unity? Есть вопрос, на него можно дать ответ